Crawl space encapsulation question
I got recommendation to have my crawl space encapsulation and with dehumidifier. The company who sent the inspector said it will reduce the humidity on my soil.
However, my question is that if the problem is that my soil will be wet and a bit muddy after big rain, without fixing that issue first, but then I encapsulate my crawl space, will that make the soil even more wet since it won't vapor effectively?  also, even I use dehumidifier, since it's encapsulated already, it will only control the humidity above the barrier sheet which cover the ground, but won't control the humidity on the soil , if my concept is correct?   Thank you
